# Get data from selected item in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, listviewitem

I have the following C# code that generate an items for list view:

```
//function that generated items for list view

 results = //An array

                    foreach (var item in results)
                    {
                        var nameStr = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
                        var descriptionStr = item.Email;
                        IconTextGrid.Items.Add(new { Name = nameStr, Description = descriptionStr });

                }
```

And the XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IconTextDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220" Height="60" Background="#FF7CC6FF">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="IconTextGrid"  SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IconTextDataTemplate}" Height="400"  Grid.Row="5" Margin="40,20,40,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" SelectionChanged="IconTextGrid_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="6"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                </ListView>
```

and:

```
private void SendRequests_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string emailAdress;
            for (int i = 0; i < IconTextGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                //I need to get the description of the selected items
            }
        }
```

My question is how Ican get the value of the Description field in the item that generated?
Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Where do you need `Description`? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: The description is here : Text="{Binding Description}" And I updated my code

Comment: what type of item.Email ?

Comment: It's cell in array that contains string

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom type like this:

```
class MyType
{
     string Name { get; set; }
     string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
IconTextGrid.Items.Add(new MyType{ Name = nameStr, Description = descriptionStr });
```

And now you can get description:

```
for (int i = 0; i < IconTextGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = (MyType)IconTextGrid.SelectedItems[i];
            string description = item.Description;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an anonymous type ofr the items in your listbox:

```
IconTextGrid.Items.Add(new { Name = nameStr, Description = descriptionStr });
```

You should declare a class:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and use this class instead:

```
IconTextGrid.Items.Add(new MyItem { Name = nameStr, Description = descriptionStr });
```

The you can get `SelectedItem` and cast it to `MyItem`.